# Passing an empty/none argument for flask url (@main.route/)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code that gets variables from a WTForm where a user can enter either a name or id, which will be used for a query in my database. The problem is that the URL 'breaks' when only one field is submitted because, for example, if no piname is submitted the url will look like '/find_pi//1424524'. Is there any way that will fix this without having to break up the code? My next task involves multiple 'optional' fields that will be harder to break up.

```
    @main.route('/find_pi/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def pick_pi():
        form = PeopleFinder()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            piname = form.piname.data
            piid = form.piid.data
            return redirect(url_for('.piresults', piname=piname, piid=piid)
        return render_template('specify_pi.html', form=form)

    @main.route('/find_pi/<piname>/<piid>')
    def find_pi(piname, piid):
        if piname != None:
            entries = Grant.query.filter(Grant.pi_name==(piname)).all()
            return render_template('piresults.html', entries=entries)
        if piid != None:
            entries = Grant.query.filter(Grant.pi_id==(piid)).all()
            return render_template('piresults.html', entries=entries)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need either `piname` or `piid` there are a couple ways to implement this:

1.Separate routes

```
@main.route('find_pi/<str:piname>') 
def find_pi_by_name(piname):
    entries = Grant.query.filter(Grant.pi_name==(piname)).all()
    return render_template('piresults.html', entries=entries)

@main.route('find_pi/<int:piid>') # int ensures that piid is a number
def find_pi_by_id(piid):
    entries = Grant.query.filter(Grant.pi_id==(piid)).all()
    return render_template('piresults.html', entries=entries)
```

2.Single route that checks both piname and piid

```
@main.route('/find_pi/<piname_or_piid>')
def find_pi(piname_or_piid):
    piid = None
    piname = None
    try:
       piid = int(piname_or_piid)
    except ValueError:
       piname = piname_or_piid
    if piname != None:
        entries = Grant.query.filter(Grant.pi_name==(piname)).all()
    elif piid != None:
        entries = Grant.query.filter(Grant.pi_id==(piid)).all()
    return render_template('piresults.html', entries=entries)
```

If you're planning to add other optional parameters then you should use the querystring, the base url isn't a good place to put optional elements.